# Find the minimal polynomial of $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> Let $a=\sqrt[4]2+\sqrt2$
>   
> a) Is it true that $\mathbb Q(a)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt[4]2)$?
>   
> b) Find the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb Q$
>   
> c) Find the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$
>   
>  d) Is it true that $\sqrt[3]2\in \mathbb Q(a)$?

In b) I have: $$a=\sqrt[4]2+\sqrt2$$
$$a^2-2\sqrt2a+2=\sqrt2$$
$$a^4-4a^2-8a+2=0$$
So we get the polynomial $f(a)=a^4-4a^2-8a+2$ and from Eisenstein's criterion we know that it is irreductible polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ so it is minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$.

In c) I have: $$g(a)=a^2-3\sqrt2a+2$$

**But I don't know how to do a) and d)**

Comment: For d) maybe consider degrees.  For a) one direction of inclusion should be clear.  The other shouldn't be that hard, but considering degrees may work again here.

Comment: @sharding4 I don't really understand how I can use degrees here so that they help me in a) and d). Can you develop your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

For a) you can use that $a^2-2\sqrt2a+2=\sqrt2$, and so $a^2+2=\sqrt2 (1+2a)$, thus
$$
\sqrt2=\frac{a^2+2}{2a+1} \in \mathbb Q(a).
$$
From there we also get $\sqrt[4]{2} = a - \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb Q(a)$, and so $\mathbb Q(a)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt[4]2)$.

For d) note that the minimum polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $X^3 - 2$, so then if $\sqrt[3]2\in \mathbb Q(a)$, then $[\mathbb Q(a) : \mathbb Q]$ would be divisible by 3 by the tower law, a contradiction.

As a sidenode: one way to tackle a) with degrees would be to note that since $\mathbb Q(a)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt[4]2)$, thus it's dimension must be 1, 2 or 4. Then one can show $1, a$ and $a^2$ are linearly independent by expressing them in the basis $\{1, \sqrt 2, \sqrt[4]2, \sqrt 2 \sqrt[4]2\}$ of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt[4]2)$ - thus the dimension must be 4 and we must have $\mathbb Q(a) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt2, \sqrt[4]2)$